# ViewFlipper with text below

Tags: java, android

I have the following xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" >


            </ViewFlipper>

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my java class I'm loading online images in the ViewFlipper and I'm starting an animation. The point is I also want the two TextViews to be animated along with the ViewFlipper (slide left), on condition that they still below the ViewFlipper.

Any help please ?

Comment: wrap that text inside viewflipper as viewflipper is child of viewgroup

Comment: wrapping the text inside the viewflipper will make him slide next to him. I want the text to remain under the viewflipper while sliding

Comment: use linearlayout inside viewflipper